How to make Two Android wearables communicate using NFC?
I am developing an Android wearable (Wear OS 4) standalone application in which two wearables must exchange their unique ID as a one-time thing (Just pairing). The plan was to use NFC p2p to exchange data with each other but recently found that NFC p2p (Android Beam) is deprecated in API > 29. The next best option was to use Nearby devices API, but it involved creating extra screens(send, receive, list devices and consent) in the application, extra permissions and was more battery-consuming, considering the pairing was a one-time feature. Are there any third-party libraries that I can use to directly use NFC p2p? or what different approaches should I proceed with? I'm also planning to support Tizen devices in future, so using Android nearby, restricts me from doing that.

Why don't use Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) for this task ? THe pairing process is (built-in) and BLE is available on more devices as NFC.

Will give it a try. But still the number of screens remain the same.

It's hard to get 2 full devices to communicate via NFC, never mind 2 restricted wearable device, bluetooth or wifi much better than NFC.

Unfortunately, most Wear OS devices don't support reading NFC, so you're better off using BLE as @MichaelFehr said.
